# Properties of functions in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support $K$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ suppose also $f$ has compact support, name such support $K$, defining

$$
\begin{array}{l}
x_m = \inf K \\
x_M = \sup K \\
\end{array}
$$

we must have $f(x_m) = f(x_M) = 0$, what I'd like to know is if for each $n$ we have
$$
f^{(n)}(x_m) = f^{(n)}(x_M) = 0
$$

I think this might be true and I'm attempting to prove it.
Suppose $f^{(1)}(x_m) > 0$ then we would have a neighborhood $\mathcal{U}(x_m)$ where $f$ is strictly increasing, but $f(x_m)$ is 0 which implies that there's some point $y \in \mathcal{U(x_m)}, y < x_m$ where $f(y) < f(x_m) = 0$ but then $x_m$ wouldn't be the $\inf K$. We can do the same for $x_M$, and by induction we can prove this for each $n$, since $supp (f^{(1)}) = K$ and $f^{(1)} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Much better to note simply that $f'$ is a $C^\infty$ function with compact support and proceed by induction (note that your last identity in general fails).

Comment: Ok, but how do you prove that? probably the equality should be set inclusion I guess. Also is my proof wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to check your argument is correct when there a trivial argument?

Comment: Because it's trivial doesn't mean it's correct. I'm not a mathematician so it's very likely I make mistakes.

Comment: Let me explain. Note that any derivative of a $C^\infty$  function with compact support $K$ is again a $C^\infty$ function with compact support (contained in $K$: if a point $x$ outside $K$ is in the support of $f'$, then necessarily $f$ is not constant in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $x$ and so indeed $x\in K$). Now you can use induction on the degree of the derivative. You have $$f(x_m)=f(x_M)=0$$ and so also $$f'(x_m)=f'(x_M)=0,$$ etc, because either $x_m$ and/or $x_M$ are the same as before, or because they are outside the support of $f'$.

Comment: I understand, so you proved it by contradiction.  But my argument is correct as well, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely trivial from the *definition*.

Let $V=\Bbb R\setminus K$. Then $V$ is an open set and $f=0$ in $V$. Since $V$ is open this shows that $f^{(n)}=0$ in $V$, and now since $x_m,x_M\in \overline  V$ and $f^{(n)}$ is continuous it follows that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for $x=x_m,x_M$.

Comment: Does as similar result hold if instead of $\mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: @user8469759 Does anything in the proof change if $\Bbb R$ is replaced by $\Bbb R^N$?

Comment: It shouldn't. You would change $f^{(n)}$ with differentials of order $n$ I guess, right?